# Flutter firebase user problem trying to link to a model

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

the error I'm getting:

> A value of type 'UserA?' can't be returned from the method
> '_userFromFirebaseUser' because it has a return type of 'User'

I'm following along this tutorial: [Flutter & Firebase App Tutorial #6 - Custom User Model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PS0b2gJ04Bs)

At about 5:35 into the video he talks about returning the Firebase user object and linking it to the model.  Now the video is about 2 years old, so Firebase has moved on a bit. FirebaseUser is now just called User, but I think in my changes I've made a mistake.  Here is my code:

```
class AuthService{
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //create user object based on firebaseuser
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
    return user != null ? UserA(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }
```

This is my model:

```
class UserA {
   final String uid;

  UserA({ required this.uid });
}
```

Since FirebaseUser is now just called User I've changed the model to be UserA since I was getting confused.

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up the two types of users in your code.

The video has two types: `FirebaseUser` and `User`, which you have mapped to `Users` and `UserA` respectively.

With your types, the function should be:

```
UserA? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
  return user != null ? UserA(uid: user.uid) : null;
}
```

Aside from the type change, the `?` is needed in Dart nowadays to indicate that you may return either a `UserA` object or `null`.

Comment: yep that solved it!.  I didn't add the ? after UserA?

Comment: That, and you were trying to return `User` instead of `UserA`.